# Are there some common ways to catalogue tar tape backups?

Tags: tar, tape

So, I have a tape drive, and use it to permanently archive some stuff (old projects). These are "copy once" things, no versioning/incremental backups/etc. Though of course, new projects might be added to a tape later on.

I use tar for this (GNU tar 1.29 on Ubuntu 18.04):

```bsh
tar --create --verbose --verbose --blocking-factor=128 --checkpoint=10000  
 --checkpoint-action="echo=[%{%F %T}t] [%s] #%u: %T" --format=posix
 --label="`date -Iseconds`" --totals --multi-volume --file=/dev/nst0 <Folders to backup>
```

Since this leaves me with a bunch of tapes that I have to manually keep track of, I wonder if there are common tools to catalogue those tapes, and maybe even keep track of stuff like the blocking factor, etc.

I know I can manually run a `tar --list` into a file and keep notes, which is my current approach, but before I start off wrong, I figure I ask.

I am not looking at "big" programs like bacula/bareos and the like, mainly because I want to be able to restore with just the tape in hand and a brand new *NIX system. With tar, I know that I can just scan every tape to find what I need in an emergency. (But I'd like to avoid that, hence the question)

Comment: I cannot recommend your `gtar` usage since `gtar` is known to reject follow up tapes from multi volume archives with a probability of ~ 5%. Also note that your command happily archives long pathnames that gnu tar later rejects to restore. Did you think about whether you really like to use `gtar`for backups?

Comment: @schily Thanks! Haven't heard of that, that's interesting. Does that apply to posix-format as well? `tar --show-defaults` says it's using gnu format by default, which is documented to have incompatible extensions. I was hoping that by using POSIX.1-2001, I get a broad compatibility with different systems (while also supporting large files). Do you recommend something else that runs on Linux (and optionally, BSD)?

Comment: The main problem with gtar is that it is not cleanly written and does not correctly control the use of features based on  a current archive format. I recommend `star` that is recent in `schilytools`. If you like to verify that `gtar` does not support long pathnames, try to extract the file `star/testscripts/longpath.tar.bz2` using `star` and `gtar`.

Comment: @schily `star` doesn't support multi-volume archives in pax format - is that a limitation of the pax standard? The output (along with -block-number) is pretty good for my cataloging needs, so that's neat. experimenting with this command line for now: `star -c artype=xstar -block-number blocks=128 file=/dev/st0 -fifo -fifostats fs=1g -multivol -time -v -v VOLHDR="``date -Iseconds``" <Folders>`

Comment: The `pax` format is strictly POSIX compliant and does not impmement extensions. For backups, I recommend the option `-dump` that switches to the `exustar` format plus additional meta data. A blocksize of 128 is not supported by all hardware, 126 is recommended for best portability. `-fifo` is the default since 30 years. Make sure to use at least release 1.6.1, since before there have been some hangs in the fifo on Linux.

Comment: @schily Thanks. I grabbed schily-2019-11-11 from sourceforge and compiled it, `star --version` shows "star: star 1.6.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) 2019/11/01 Options: find fflags remote Linux-xattr". Linux Kernel is "4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, I went with [`star`](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/star.html), which gave me a good output using `` -block-number -v -v VOLHDR="`date -Iseconds`" ``. I can use this as a catalogue.

```bsh
block         0: a   0   0 V---------  root/root Nov 18 02:26 2019 2019-11-18T02:26:47-05:00 --Volume Header--
block         3: a       0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root/root Nov 18 02:25 2019 ./
block         6: a 17656337143 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root/root Dec 22 13:20 2016 Project1.zip
```

I can also extract the tape with either star or GNU tar (without some of the extended attributes - but that's fine, this is my "in case of an apocalypse" fallback).